# Binary tree C++ basics

Tags: c++

```
void BinarySearchTree::insert(int d)
{
    tree_node* t = new tree_node;
    tree_node* parent;
    t->data = d;
    t->left = NULL;
    t->right = NULL;
    parent = NULL;

    // is this a new tree?
    if(isEmpty()) root = t;
    else
    {
        //Note: ALL insertions are as leaf nodes
        tree_node* curr;
        curr = root;
        // Find the Node's parent
        while(curr)
        {
            parent = curr;
            if(t->data > curr->data) curr = curr->right;
            else curr = curr->left;
        }

        if(t->data < parent->data)
           parent->left = t;
        else
           parent->right = t;
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Why do I need to allocate memory for **tree_node* t;** using new but not for **tree_node* parent;**?
2. What exactly is tree_node* what does it look like in memory and what does it do?
3. Can someone explain to me the -> operator and how it works?

Comment: tree_node* t is being used as a new node, the one that will be inserted, while parent is just a temporary storage variable used to store parents nodes during processing. The `->` operator is an accessor so that you can get data stored within the object. As for what tree_node actually is? That's probably a custom data type made specifically for this tree implementation. You'd have to look through your source for it.

Comment: The `->` means the same thing as `.` in other languages; it references members of an object.  So `parent->right` means the `right` member in the `parent` object.

Comment: @RobertHarvey well... parent is not an object, but a pointer.

Comment: It points to an object, right?  Otherwise, being merely a pointer, it wouldn't have any members. :)

Comment: @Undermine2k: Sounds a lot like you need to learn the basics of c/c++. That would pretty much answer most of your questions. http://www.cplusplus.com has decent enough tutorials

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why do I need to allocate memory for tree_node* t; using new but not for tree_node* parent;?

You don't **need** to, but it's part of the logic. `t` represents the new node you're inserting, so you need to create it first (which is done by the `new`). You don't allocate memory for `parent` because it will refer to an already existing node:

```
 while(curr)
 {
    parent = curr;
    //...
```

> What exactly is tree_node* what does it look like in memory and what does it do?

No way to tell (it should be defined somewhere), but it's probably a structure like so:

```
struct tree_node
{
    tree_node* left;
    tree_node* right;
    int data;
}
```

> Can someone explain to me the -> operator and how it works?

It's for accessing object members through a pointer. If you have `Class* x`, then `x->a` is equivalent to `(*x).a`.